# Is there a way to remove Ifs and use functions instead

Tags: ruby

Is there a way in Ruby to replace 'if' statements for a function to make the code more readable?

```
if Environ == :windows
    puts 'windows'
else
    if Environ == :linux 
        puts 'linux'
    else
        puts 'other environment'
    end
end
```

I want to replace the above with blocks like:

```
windows{
    puts 'windows'
}

linux{
    puts 'linux'
    others{
        puts 'other environment'
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using `elsif` or `case` instead of inventing new methods that the reader has to look up in order to understand.

Comment: Your code is unnecessarily complex. Combine the lines `else` and `if Environ == :linux` to `elsif Environ == :linux` and remove the final `end`. When learning a new language being overly-distracted by diversions is a time-waster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a function that accepts a block, but it makes no sense (and isn't really possible) to nest `other` inside `linux`.

```rb
def windows
  yield if Environ == :windows
end

def linux
  yield if Environ == :linux
end

def other
  yield if Environ != :windows && Environ != :linux
end

windows {
  puts 'windows'
}

linux {
  puts 'linux'
}

other {
  puts 'other'
}
```

The better solution in this case might be a simple `case` statement:

```rb
case Environ
when :windows then puts "windows"
when :linux then puts "linux"
else puts "other"
end
```

Comment: You can collapse the `case` a little by moving the `puts` outside of the `case`.

Comment: @tadman I suspect the `puts` is there only to demonstrate branching, and are not present in the actual code - much less as lone statements

Comment: @tadman This is placeholder code. If the objective were to just `puts` something, the whole question could be replaced with `puts Environ.to_s`